# Relate Homogeneous Coefficients In LODE System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the system of LODEs:

$ y_1(t)' = -3y_1(t) -4y_2(t) +11t + 15 $

$ y_2(t)' = 5y_1(t) + 6y_2(t) + 3e^{-t} -15t -20 $

I separate out and solve for $y_1$ and $y_2$:

eq. (I) $ (D+3)y_1 + 4y_2 = 11t + 15 $

eq. (II) $-5y_1 + (D-6)y_2 = e^{-t} - 15t -20 $

$ (D^2 -3D + 2)y_1 = 1 - 6t -12e^{-t} $

$ (D^2 -3D + 2)y_2 = 10t +6e^{-t} $

Solving the H-LODE of these equations gets the set of solutions:

$ y_{H1} = a_1e^t + b_1e^{2t} $

$ y_{H2} = a_2e^t + b_2e^{2t} $

I need to relate the coefficients $a_1$ and $a_2$, $b_1$ and $b_2$ in terms of $c_1$ and $c_2$. If I plug $y_{H1}$ and $y_{H2}$ back into the H-LODEs of eq. (I) and eq. (II) and sum, I get $a_1 = -a_2 = c_1$, but the $b$ terms cancel out. How do I relate $b_1$ and $b_2$?

Comment: You don't need to pass through a second order equation; that might make these first steps easier but then it makes this last step that you're stuck on a huge pain. Instead, consider $y'(t)-Ay(t)=b(t)$, where $A$ is a fixed matrix. Multiply both sides by $e^{-At}$ to get $\frac{d}{dt} \left ( e^{-At} y(t) \right ) = e^{-At} b(t)$. So $y(t)=y_0+e^{At} \int_0^t e^{-As} b(s) ds$. Compute the matrix exponential and do the integration.

Comment: @Ian I updated the post to clarify that $y_1$ and $y_2$ are functions. I'm a bit lost on what you said honestly. Your equation only has one function of y. When I solve for those I got the 2nd order ODE. How did you get that?

Comment: My $y(t)$ is a vector $(y_1,y_2)$. I solve for $y_1$ and $y_2$ simultaneously with this approach.

Comment: If you really want to carry out your approach, you'll need to use the initial conditions: you know $y_1(0),y_2(0)$ (those should be given) and so you also know $y_1'(0),y_2'(0)$ from the original ODE system. So you can find the necessary coefficients for your $y_1$ and $y_2$ expressions. (Except that your $y_1$ and $y_2$ expressions are wrong because you did not include any "particular solution" term. This can be corrected but you did not do it.) But this is likely to be messy, requiring you to solve four equations in four unknowns. It is much easier to just use the matrix exponential.

Comment: @Ian Intriguing, but I'll have to look into the matrix thing some time later, got too much on my plate atm. Just for clarification, this is not complete; rest did not have any relevance to my question. The particular solutions are rather straight forward to obtain. The final general solution(no initial conditions are given) with the $a$ and $b$ terms related is the following: $y_1 = c_1e^t + 4c_2 e^2t -2e^{-t} - 3t -4$, $y_2 = -c_1e^t - 5c_2e^{2t} +e^{-t} + 5t +15/2$. Only 2 unknowns. I may try and ask my professor, but that usually results in belittling scolding... I do appreciate the help.

Comment: You need to include the particular solutions in order to find $c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4$ correctly. The thing is, there are "really" only two arbitrary constants; splitting into two second order ODEs is what created two more.